# How to initialize variable of another class in java?

Tags: java, variables

I have two classes, one is people and 2nd is the person now I have made people class as a data type in the person class and variable name is the position

```
public person
{
  people position; 
}
```

now how can I use this position variable and what type of data can be used to initialize this variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use common naming conventions:

```
public class Person {
    People position;
}
```

The type of data you use to initialize the `position` variable is `People`, because that's the data type you've defined it as.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response, but could you please give me an example code if possible?

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far, what you've found in your research, and I can help from there if you have specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

`position` will be initialized with `null` when you create a new `Person` instance. If you want to initialize it to another value you can write a constructor and pass a `Person` instance (or a subclass of `Person`) to the constructor and assign the `Person` instance to `position`.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know the detail of your People class, so i assume its empty like this

```
public class People {

}

public class Person {
    People position;
}
```

then if you do nothing in the constructor, the implementation can be something like this

```
Person newPerson= new Person();
newPerson.position=new People();
```